# Why won't an external executable run without manual input from the terminal command line?

Tags: bash, python-2.7, unix

I am currently writing a Python script that will pipe some RNA sequences (strings) into a UNIX executable, which, after processing them, will then send the output back into my Python script for further processing. I am doing this with the subprocess module.

However, in order for the executable to run, it must also have some additional arguments provided to it. Using the subprocess.call method, I have been trying to run:

```
import subprocess

seq= "acgtgagtag"
output= subprocess.Popen(["./DNAanalyzer", seq])
```

Despite having my environmental variables set properly, the executables running without problem from the command line of the terminal, and the subprocess module functioning normally (e.g. subprocess.Popen(["ls"]) works just fine), the Unix executable prints out the same output:

```
Failed to open input file acgtgagtag.in
Requesting input manually.
```

There are a few other Unix executables in this package, and all of them behave the same way. I even tried to create a simple text file containing the sequence and specify it as the input in both the Python script as well as within the command line, but the executables only want manual input.

I have looked through the package's manual, but it does not mention why the executables can ostensibly be only run through the command line. Because I have limited experience with this module (and Python in general), can anybody indicate what the best approach to this problem would be?

Comment: Could it be the program and you have different ideas about the current working directory? To test this hypothesis, use an absolute filename for `seq = "/some/dir/acgtgagtag"` . And note that in the error message the file has a ".in" suffix... not in seq.

Comment: Does `./DNAanalyzer acgtgagtag` from a terminal give the same error? This is not the same as running `./DNAanalyzer` and then entering `acgtgagtag`.  It sounds like the program expects a filename while you're giving it a string.

Comment: @thatotherguy the ./DNAanalyzer does not give the same error from the terminal, since it automatically brings up the options that allow the input to be manually typed in. In any case, the manual for executables says that the file must be given in the command line as a string.

Comment: And in reference to the suggestions made by @Jens I have already tried giving it an absolute filename, both in the Python script and in the terminal. Neither works.

Comment: @BobMcBobson Have you noticed that it complains about `acgtgagtag.in` and not `acgtgagtag`?

Comment: @thatotherguy true it did not complain about acgtgagtag. but i just actually figured out the answer, will answer it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Popen()` is actually a constructor for an object – that object being a "sub-shell" that directly runs the executable.  But because I didn't set a standard input or output (`stdin` and `stdout`), they default to `None`, meaning that the process's I/O are both closed.

What I should have done is pass `subprocess.PIPE` to signify to the `Popen` object that I want to pipe input and output between my program and the process.

Additionally, the environment variables of the script (in the main shell) were not the same as the environment variables of the subshell, and these specific executables needed certain environment variables in order to function (in this case, it was the path to the parameter files in its package). This was done in the following fashion:

```
import subprocess as sb

seq= "acgtgagtag"
my_env= {BIOPACKAGEPATH: "/Users/Bobmcbobson/Documents/Biopackage/"}

p= sb.Popen(['biopackage/bin/DNAanalyzer'], stdin=sb.PIPE, stdout=sb.PIPE, env=my_env)
strb = (seq + '\n').encode('utf-8')
data = p.communicate(input=strb)
```

After creating the `Popen` object, we send it a formatted input string using `communicate()`. The output can now be read, and further processed in whatever way in the script.